# Добавление свойства в объект js

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть функция, которая принимает строку любых символов и возвращает только числа в виде строки.

Задача состоит в том, чтоб написать другую функцию, которая будет возвращать объект, в котором ключ - это цифра строки, полученной предыдущей функцией, а свойство - сколько раз повторяется эта цифра в строке.

Вопрос такой - как задать свойство?

Я реализовал таким образом:

```js
function countNumber(str) {
  let obj = {}
  //makeNumber работает ок, не обращаем внимание
  let stringOfNumbers = makeNumber(str);

  for (let i = 0; i < stringOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    obj[stringOfNumbers[i]] = 1;
  }

}
```

потом `If-ОМ` проверяем, есть ли уже такое значение и т.д, но сама проблема в том, что не задается свойство и я никак не могу сообразить, как задать нужное мне название свойства.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Все, спасибо) нашел такой вот метод Object.defineProperty(), уже получилось подстроить под решение

Comment: Object.defineProperty в данном случае ничем не отличается от того, что у тебя в коде